# iOS - return number of files matching a naming scheme

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, file, uiimage

Is there an easy way to return a number of files that conform to a set naming scheme? Trying to make cheap and easy image sequence player. I have the heavy lifting done but currently have to pass it the number of files in each sequence which is a pain to update.

> example
>
> Image1_000 Image1_001 Image2_000 Image2_001 Image2_002

So if the naming scheme was set to Image2_ it would return 3 and if the naming scheme was set to Image1_ it would return 2.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean but a combination of [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:] and then some NSRegularExpression to do the matching would probably be the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this pretty easily with the help of `NSPredicate`, where you define a regular expression like syntax. This happens like so:

```
NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundleRoot error:nil];
NSArray *onlyImagesStartWithTwo = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self BEGINSWITH 'Image2_'"]];
```

This `NSArray *onlyImagesStartWithTwo` will have all images starting with `Image2_`.

Hope this helps...

Comment: This seems like the best path for me to follow. It does seem to have one snag tho, using bundlePath is causing a crash although Xcode seems to recognize bundlePath.

Comment: can u post the reason for the crash? One way to subvert this is, if you know exactly where the image files are ex. Documents directory or caches dir etc. then u can specify that directly...

Comment: It's crashing with an "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" on the "NSArray *dirContents" line, at that point bundleRoot correctly tells me where that .App is.

users/Me/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/<long AlphaNumeric String>/TheApp.App

Also throws an error at the same point an ipad

Comment: maybe there are no files. see if there are those `image2_*` files present. so when at crashes at `[dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self BEGINSWITH 'Image2_'"]];` ? strange. This is production grade code...

Comment: Working now... was a malformed count statement that was erroring a few lines down and just appearing on that line.

Answer (score 0):

if these are NSStrings in an NSArray:

```
int counter = 0;
for (NSString *str in strArray) {
    if ([[[str componentsSeperatedByString:@"_"] objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:namingScheme]){
        counter++;
    }
}
```